# Matlab operator : used with a vector

Tags: matlab

I have the following simple piece of Matlab code:

```
a = [100 100 100 100 5]
b = [0]
c = b:a
```

c is a vector going from 0 to 100... I would like to understand why the last value is 100 since a is vector... does it take the first element?

Comment: What output did you expect to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [`colon (:)`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html) takes only scalars as input your `a` is interpreted as `a(1)`, and so you get `c = 0:100`.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, if you tell what you want to do will help you and the people try to answer. In this code it gives c=0 to 100 which have 101 elements. If you are trying to merge the matrix a and b you can try `c=[b a];` for same row. it gives c= 0 100 100 100 100 5